# IntelliJ: Unable to use class from jar dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, import, dependencies

I am trying to test setting up a minimal project, building and exporting it as a jar, and using that project as a dependency in another. I am using Spring for this. I have two projects, `makeajar` and `useajar`. In makeajar, I set up a simple project with a Java class called `Dinner`. I want to import the jar for this project as part of the library in useajar, and from useajar instantiate a Dinner object.

However, the issue I'm getting is that I can't import the Dinner class. When I do, the import shows red:

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong in this process?

**Things I've already tried:**

- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Creating a fresh project
- Adding makeajar as a module dependency (note: This was already there, and also appeared in the Project Structure -> Libraries)

**How I produce the jar file from `makeajar`:**

- Go to project root directory and run `./gradlew build`

**Things I'm noticing:**

- Although makeajar appears in my module dependencies and libraries, it does not appear in the "External Libraries" folder in the useajar project.
- I can gradle refresh fine, and if I comment out the attempts to import the Dinner object, I build.
- I can easily get various popular dependencies (i.e. Jackson, guava) from MavenCentral and use these right out of the box. The issue is only occurring with my makeajar dependency.

`makeajar` build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.12.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.makingajar'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`useajar` build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.12.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    mavenLocal {
        flatDir {
        dirs projectDir.toString() + '/libs'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
        implementation 'com.makingajar:makeajar2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.3'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

IntelliJ version 2020.1.4
Gradle version 6.6.1

Comment: Also, in case it wasn't clear, Gradle is building successfully up until I try to import the Dinner class in the `useajar` project. It is successfully able to find the jar in my project's `/lib` folder. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is all of your capitalization correct? I noticed that your "Useajar" class had its first letter capitalized, but the import of "makeajar" is all lowercase.

Comment: Good thought. But I can confirm the capitalization is correct!

Comment: What about the namespace? The "UseAJar" namespace is com.EXAMPLE.useajar, but com.MAKINGAJAR.makeajar; I haven't used any IDE's (or even Java) in a while so sorry if these seem like obvious solutions.

Comment: Your implementation dep is called com.makingajar:makeajar2 - should there definitely be 2 at the end?